# How to get table name from string that contain SELECT statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, string

i have a string that contain a sql command,

something like this:

> strCommand = "Select [Feild1], 
>   [Feild2] 
>   From TableName
>   Order By [Feild1] desc" ;

How can find table name in this string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solutions so far have all gone with the searching within strings approach.  You've not mentioned if your SQL queries will always look similar, but there are many variants of a query to include which these solutions will break on.  Consider...

- `SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM TableName`
- `SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM [TableName]`
- `SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM dbo.TableName`
- `SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table1Name, Table2Name`

If the query you're trying to parse is one you have the database for, you can get SQL server to do the hard work of parsing the query for you, instead of trying to account for all the cases in SQL.  You can execute a query using `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON`, which will produce a table of the query plan.  You can then analyse the Arguments column, which contains all of the fields the query will involve in a standard format.  An example program is below:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING);
conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Field1], [Field2] FROM [TableName]";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

Regex objectRegex = new Regex(@"^OBJECT:\(\[(?<database>[^\]]+)\]\.\[(?<schema>[^\]]+)\]\.\[(?<table>[^\]]+)\]\.\[(?<field>[^\]]+)\]\)$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

List<string> lstTables = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string argument = row["Argument"].ToString();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(argument))
    {
        Match m = objectRegex.Match(argument);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            string table = m.Groups["schema"] + "." + m.Groups["table"];
            if (!lstTables.Contains(table))
            {
                lstTables.Add(table);
            }
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Query uses the following tables: " + String.Join(", ", lstTables));
```

This will deal with all forms of query name and return all tables which are involved in the query, no matter how they are included.

Comment: Putting this regex and a simple select in an online tester returns no match...

Answer (score 2):

If this is the same pattern all of the time then:

```
 string tableName = strCommand.Split(' ', strCommand)[4];
```

but if you can add / remove fields just iterate through the splitted string and search for "From", and the next string will be your table name

Answer (score 1):

I would say- what is after "From" as a more reliable way of getting the table name. Loop through the array created, when you reach "From", the next one is the table.

Comment: what happen when strCommand = "Select [Field1] as From,[field2] as Alias   
From TableName"  ????? :)

Comment: this is not a valid sql statement though - From is a keyword that you can't use there

Comment: @HosseinMahMOODY: It will be "Select [Field1] as [From],[field2] as Alias From TableName" because from is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Method which gives us tablename just change the SQL query string, connection String

Works with simple query, joins too

```
public static List<string> getTablenames(string connString, string QueryString)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
    con.Open();
    DataTable dt = con.GetSchema("Tables");

    List<string> getTableName = new List<string>();
    List<string> tablenames = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
       tablenames.Add(dr[2].ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string myTable = tablenames[i];
        Boolean checkMyTable = QueryString.Contains(myTable);
        if (checkMyTable == true)
            getTableName.Add(myTable);
    }
    con.Close();
    return getTableName;
}
```

Comment: Check question's title again.

Comment: @HosseinMahMOODY - Read suggested answer again!

Comment: If you will try your query with this method, it will return a single length List.

Comment: oh,sorry,I was wrong,Your solution is correct.thanks and Sorry again.

Comment: This will match substrings and may find table names in other places.  Consider a database with Person and Address tables, and the Person table contains AddressId.  `SELECT PersonId, AddressId FROM Person` would return both Person and Address, even though Address isn't in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the substring (This way it does not matter how many column you have to select)

```
string table = strCommand.ToLower().Substring(strCommand.IndexOf("FROM".ToLower())).Split(' ')[0];
```

Comment: Tested and it returns "from". To get this nice prospering piece of code working you should use .Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]. Why? First of all, IndexOf returns position of keyword "FROM" and Substring gets part of the base string starting from that position, so you need to get the very next item, which is the table name. And second, if you pass an empty array of char instead of space explicitly, Split will use any whitespace delimiter such as new line and tab, etc. and if you use RemoveEmptyEntries, there can be more than one delimiting whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

ISun's answer met my needs but one change is required to get the table name:

```
string table = strCommand.ToLower().Substring(strCommand.IndexOf("FROM".ToLower())).Split(' ')[1];
```

not

```
string table = strCommand.ToLower().Substring(strCommand.IndexOf("FROM".ToLower())).Split(' ')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution in SQL, try this

```
declare @q varchar(1000) = 'Select [Feild1], [Feild2] From TableName Order By [Feild1] desc',
        @tableName varchar(100) = '',
        @temp varchar(1000),
        @temp2 char(1)

declare @frmIndex int = CHARINDEX('From', @q, 0);
declare @flag int = 0, @counter int = 1;
select @temp = SUBSTRING(@q, @frmIndex, len(@q))

set @temp = LTRIM(REPLACE(@temp,'From',''))

while(@flag <> 1)
begin
    set @temp2 = SUBSTRING(@temp, @counter, 1)
    if(@temp2 = ' ')
        set @flag = 1
    select @tableName = @tableName + @temp2
    set @counter = @counter + 1
end

select @tableName as TableName
```